# Eventlogger events not showing up in Event Grid control

Tags: twincat

We are trying to set up an eventlogger in our HMI project.  We see events in "Logged Events" window, but cannot see them in the HMI event grid.  The server extensions in our HMI also do not contain the eventlogger extension as the documentation shows.

Do you have any ideas why these are not showing up?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you solve it? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

From Beckhoff:

- Add the package for the Event Logger:
- Manage NuGet Packages...

[image]

- select: "Browse"
- search: "beckhoff hmi"
- choose: Beckhoff.TwinCAT.HMLEventLogger
- install

[image]